# Ember Octane Logout button disappears

Tags: ember.js

I am upgrading to Ember Octane and I modified the template HBS to call the component JS. When I use Ember Classic, the Logout button exists and works. But, when I convert to Octane then the Logout button disappears. o_O

What is the correct way to display a Logout button on the template HBS? Note: I do not have a component HBS file. Is this required in Ember Octane?

Classic Template HBS snippet:

```
<li><a href="#" onclick={{action "logout"}}>Logout</a></li>
```

Octane Template HBS snippet:

```
<li><a href="#" onclick={{on "submit" this.logout}}>Logout</a></li>
```

Octane Component JS (works with Classic Template, but not Octane Template):

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default class Navigation extends Component {    

    @service session
    @service currentClient

    @action
    logout(ev) {

        ev.preventDefault();

            this.session.invalidate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is the improper usage of `on` modifier. The `on` modifier has to be used on the element space whereas in your snippet, the `on` modifier was used as a helper.

Should be used like:

```html
<button {{on "click" this.logout}}> Logout </button>
```

This means, we are asking the framework to register the provided function `this.logout` for the  `click` event.

and **not** as:

```html
<button onclick={{on "click" this.logout}}> Logout </button>
```

[This guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/upgrading/current-edition/action-on-and-fn/) should help to migrate from classic event handling to the newest Octane way.